# Wait for a function to create modified Array

Tags: node.js, reactjs, asynchronous

I'm writing React app. After clicking one button, I want the file to be downloaded. Before that, the array that I have has to be modified in order to have the downloaded report in proper format.

The problem I have is that I don't know how to force `getReports()` to wait for `setInOrder()` to process the data. Therefore code doesn't enter the loop.

```
export const setInOrder = async (objects) => {

  var sortedObjectsAll = new Object();

  for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
    if (sortedObjectsAll.hasOwnProperty(objects[i].addedBy)) {
      sortedObjectsAll[objects[i].addedBy].push(objects[i]);
    } else {
      sortedObjectsAll[objects[i].addedBy] = new Array();
    }
  }

  return sortedObjectsAll
}

export const getReports = async (objects) => {

  const sortedObjectsAll =  await setInOrder(objects) // This is correct but not available instantly
  
  console.log(sortedObjectsAll) // this is correctly printed

  const reports = new Array();
  for (let j = 0; j < sortedObjectsAll.length; ++j) {
    console.log("Never enters here")
    reports.push(createReport(sortedObjectsAll[j]))
  }
  return reports
}
```

I'm trying to use await or async somehow, but can't solve it. I see some Promises advised but I don't know how to really return the resulting variable to the code that actually downloads the report.

Comment: What's `goals` inside `setInOrder`?

Comment: I changed it to `objects`, should be clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you do not need to write an async-await something like that, because it is not an async operation (and if you write one and do not have any await in it, it will wait for nothing).

Second you want to iterate through an object, and not through an array, and that is the problem. Replace with the following (there are other solutions as well):

```
for (const key in sortedObjectsAll) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Indeed it's not about waiting, I was confused because I wanted to iterate over object fields which wasn't happening and I thought it's because of async something.